# test command in KornShell (ksh)

Tags: shell, unix, testing, ksh

I have a question on the test command in the KornShell (ksh). I know `-ne` is for comparing integers and  `!=` is for comparing strings. How will the test command behave if one argument is a string and the other is an integer? I have below conditions in my code and both are working properly.

**Code:**

```
myCount=1
myCount=`expr $myCount+ 0`
temp=`ps -aef | grep damn | wc -l`
if [ $temp -ne $myCount]; then
        echo ERROR Number
fi

if [ $temp != $myCount ]; then
        echo ERROR Strings
fi
```

**Output:**

```
ERROR Number
ERROR Strings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is not relevant because it's a simple text substitution. In other words, the value of the variable `$temp` will be substituted in place of `$temp` (for example).

At least for the version of `ksh` I'm running, for the numeric comparison, if the value starts with a non-numeric, it will equate to 0. If it starts with a numeric but contains non-numerics, you will get an error.

For example:

```
$ export s1=xyz
$ export s2=7xyz
$ export i1=0
$ if [ $i1 -eq $s1 ]
> then
>     echo equal
> fi
equal
$ if [ $i1 -eq $s2 ]
> then
>     echo equal
> fi
ksh: 7xyz: bad number `7xyz'
```

However, based on your comments, that may not be the case for all versions of `ksh`.

Based on that, I would try to ensure that you use string comparisons for strings and numeric comparisons for numbers. Anything else may be non-portable.

Comment: Did you mean, if [ $temp -eq $myCount ]; then echo ERROR Strings fi will always print the message as far as the value of temp is non numeric.

Comment: Not quite, see the update. If the number _starts_ as a numeric but contains non-numerics, it will error. For a variable that doesn't start numeric, it's treated as 0.

Comment: On My shell, $ export s1=xyz $ export s2=7xyz $ export i1=0 $ if [ $i1 -eq $s1 ] > then > echo equal > fi $ xyz: bad

Comment: Interesting, that exact same code works on my version so I've updated the answer to basically "Don't do that" :-)

Comment: It's not necessary to use `export` in this context.

Comment: Yes, you're correct of course, but it's irrelevant to the question. I got into a habit early on in my career in exporting by default just so the variables are made available to subshells. Too much time spent wondering why my variables seemed to disappear, I guess :-)

Comment: Will myCount=`expr $myCount+ 0` converts string value to a numeric value. It may sounds silly but its a question.

Comment: Assuming that `$myCount` is numeric, I think that will work. But, if you want to force the type of a variable, look into `typeset`.

Answer (score 1):

But your code is flawed anyway.

temp=`ps -aef | grep damn | wc -l`
will always return at least 1, since it will find the grep command as well as being a string padded with leading spaces, which is why both of your tests are true.

Piping to wc is also unnecessary since the -c switch of grep will count for you.

better code would be:

temp=`ps -aef |grep damn |grep -cv grep`
which will return the number of running instances of processes containing the damn string and it will be a number.

Answer (score 0):

Using ksh93 and GNU coreutils `expr` 7.4 your command:

```
myCount=`expr $myCount+ 0`
```

gives me a syntax error and sets `myCount` to null which causes both `if` statements to output  "ksh: [: argument expected" errors. Try putting a space before the plus sign. Also, there needs to be a space before `]`.

You shouldn't need to convert `myCount` or `temp` to integers. The coercion of `myCount` using `expr` is completely unnecessary.

I prefer this form for comparing integers since it allows you to use symbolic comparison operators such as `!=` and `>` instead of `-ne` and `-gt`:

```
if (( $temp != $myCount ))
```